# OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0' when deploying to railway

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, deployment, weasyprint

I keep getting this error when I want to deploy to railway

```
from . import views

File "/app/account/views.py", line 2, in <module>

from weasyprint import HTML, CSS

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 336, in <module>

from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/css/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>

from . import computed_values, counters, media_queries

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/css/computed_values.py", line 9, in <module>

from ..text.ffi import ffi, pango, units_to_double

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/text/ffi.py", line 398, in <module>

gobject = _dlopen(

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/weasyprint/text/ffi.py", line 385, in _dlopen

return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 150, in dlopen

lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library

backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 827, in _load_backend_lib

raise OSError(msg)

OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': gobject-2.0-0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'
```

It works perfectly on my localhost and also in heroku when I first deployed to heroku.
But now, I want to migrate to railway due to the end of heroku's free service but that error keeps coming.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the problem and clarify the situation, please? What packages you're using? What are the related configs?

Answer (score 0):

Prolly - missing `'gobject-2.0-0' library,` which is a dependency of the `'weasyprint' library.` This library is used for rendering web pages to PDF or other formats. It's possible that the library is available on  local development environment &  on `Heroku`, but not  on your Railway deployment.  Few Quick checks  that'd help -

-->`Check Railway Env`: Should be  similar to your local environment or the Heroku environment in terms of dependencies. Railway uses Docker containers

--> `Missing Dependency: 'gobject-2.0-0'` is a system-level library, you may need to install it manually or through a package manager like apt-get (Ubuntu/Debian) or yum (CentOS/RedHat)

-->`Environment Variables Check`